# Complex Multiindex Sort with Categorical Values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, slice, multi-index

I have a dataframe with 4 categorical index levels:

```
grey   cat    male   ralph  ...
grey   cat    female bessie ...
yellow parrot female lisa   ...
black  dog    male   fido   ...
orange parrot female janie  ...
orange parrot male   pete   ...
black  dog    male   will   ...
grey   cat    female wanda  ...
white  dog    female karen  ...
black  cat    male   albert ...
```

I want to sort the data in the following order not referring specifically to the index values:

First by animal
Second by color
third by gender

I'll potentially want to slice by (animal,color,gender) groups.

and where first, second, and third categorical values are the same I want the records sorted in ascending alphabetical order of the 4th (see grey, cat, female below - bessie is ordered before wanda).  On thinking about this level 4 (name) may not need to be an index level?)

so the resulting dataframe would like the following (only indices shown)

```
black  cat    male   albert ...

grey   cat    female bessie ...
grey   cat    female wanda  ...

grey   cat    male   ralph  ...

black  dog    male   fido   ...
black  dog    male   will   ...

white  dog    female karen  ...

orange parrot female janie  ...

orange parrot male   pete   ...

yellow parrot female lisa   ...
```

I may use the code for other data sets so I want to write it generically (not referring to the specific contents of the data set.

I'm stumped.  Can someone provide some guidance?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried df.sortlevel ?

Comment: Thanks.  I actually wasn't aware of that function!  Wondering how I would then slice....  still learning....

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @pansen.  I've been trying sortlevel and index_sort per Andrew L.'s recommendation.  I've also been consulting the Pandas MultiIndex documentation.  I have a workaround using nested for loops.  It works but not elegant.  I want to figure out how to do it right.